# Como obtener el usuario activo en Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, apex

Estoy trabajando con oracle Apex y estoy crenaod un formulario en el modulo de PANTALLA, dentro del mismo tengo u campo de texto, en el cual necesito insertar el nombre del usuario que esta llenando el formulario, es decir el usuario activo, asi como tambien la fecha y hora.

Soy nueva trabajando en ORacle APEx si alguien me puede ayudar lo agradezco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola puedes hacer referencia al usuario logueado utilizando este comando `:app_user` y la fecha y hora seria que utilices como default de campo una consulta sql y escribas `select current_date from dual;`